# Wired Lan problem In ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lan

I am new to Ubuntu I have  installed  Ubuntu 12.04 as partition (with dual boot) using Wubi. In that my WiFi is working fine but LAN is being detected but its not working. I  have tried some of the solutions like:

I opened: `gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

I added these lines to the file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then I restarted the network:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

But still the problem persists.
Why does Ubuntu 12.04 has issues with LAN when installed?

any help would be  appreciated

Comment: If you are using NetworkManager to configure interfaces then remove the `auto eth0` and `iface eth0` lines from /etc/network/interfaces and use the NM Connection Editor to configure eth0. If you are not using NetworkManager then check your DHCP server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try Remounting the system and restart the network manager once. Your problem should be fixed. Also you can know more from this [previous thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177083/wifi-and-ethernet-connectivity-problems-after-upgrading-to-12-04) and help to solve your problem.